# Javascript onsubmit="" not working

Tags: javascript, html, form-submit, onsubmit

I'm not sure if my error comes from submitting the form to itself via PHP but it is just not hitting my function and submits anyway no matter what is returned. I'm not sure what I'm missing here. This is my form

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <title>Login Page</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/functions.js"></script>
    <!--Internal for simplicity or until bigger page -->
    <style type="text/css"> 
        #login div{display:inline;color:red;}
        input{margin-right:20px;}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<form name="login" id="login" action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>" method="POST" onsubmit="return CheckLogin()">
    <?php if($_POST && $win == false): ?>
        <div>Login Unsuccessful. Please Try Again</div><br />
    <?php endif ?>
        <input type="text" size="10" name="username" /><div></div>
            <br />
        <input type="password" size="10" name="password" /><div></div>
            <br />
    <input type="submit" text="Submit" />
</form>
<a href="register.php">Registration Page</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Really I'm just checking if username/password are empty but it just submits anyway going right through this function:

```
function CheckLogin()
{
    window.alert("made it here");
    var login = document.forms["login"];
    var user = login["username"].value;
    var pass = login["password"].value;

    if(user == null || user == "")
    {
        window.alert("user");
        return false;
    }  

    return false;
}
```

I'm sure it's something stupid that I'm missing so before I submitted this I double checked the function names and to see if I was getting any javascript errors but neither turned out to be the problem. Does anybody see my error?

The point being I do not want the PHP to run or the form to be submitted to itself if username or password is empty or null.

**EDIT** Added full html page minus the PHP functionality. Also noted that for some reason my javascript link does not 'link' instead I can view the contents of it directly in the header like it is embedded via inspect element or firebug. This might be the root of the problem but not sure why.

**EDIT** Added doctype just incase, but still no help. It is automatically embedding my javascript into my page and putting it into CDATA like you would normally instead of actually linking it. It does this in IE, Firefox & Chrome...

if anyone thinks my PHP might have something to do with it I could post it, but I don't see how server side code could interact with client side code without being posted.

Comment: The problem, as ajreal said, is that your function never returns "true".  It's also good practice to always use a semicolon in your onSubmit functions: `"return CheckLogin();"`

Comment: I copied the exact same code to a local .html file and it works (called the function and stopped the submit). It has to be some of your php var which in effect breaks format of the html output. Can you post exactly what the server echos ?

Comment: @paulsm4 I want the form to "not submit" so that I know it is hitting my function at least.

`@JimJose` The server never echo's out anything it just checks username against database and also makes sure that username/password is not an empty field. If either are empty that is where the "$log==false" portion of the code above comes into play and it says "Login Unsuccessful"

Comment: Try viewing the page source in the browser to see if thats ok. Then use firebug.

Comment: it's weird, even in viewsource it parses everything into CDATA like you would embed it instead of actually linking the file. It's doing it automatically...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some minor errors in your code. First of all there is no attribute called "text" for an input, I believe that you missed it :) Try to validate them first. [Check here](http://www.ntutorials.com/html/tag_input) to see the attributes that an input may take. Second of all, this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uUPWe/) example works properly in Chrome and FF. I cannot test in IE since I am using Ubuntu.

After I corrected the form attributes, the example in jsfiddle started to work. I am not sure whethere it's related with that, but apparently that seems the only logical explanation to me for your code not working.

Comment: Lawl... Wow... You're absolutely right. Once I changed text to value it started working. I dont even know xD ! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Your code runs fine. Try running it in another web browser. It's possible that one of the extensions you installed on your browser is causing a JS error (having Google Dictionary on Chrome was causing issues for me).

Comment: I tried in firefox over chrome but still does not work. This script is doing something that I've never seen before though. Instead of referring to the external file it is "Embedding" it into the header. If I inspect element or firebug and open the header, I am able to open the javascript tag also and see inside it instead of clicking a link. That might be the root of my problem but I cant figure out why it is doing that. I thought it was a browser update

Comment: @Howdy_McGee That's pretty normal, using both Firebug and Chrome inspector I can expand `<script>` tags. If you view source rather than inspecting, does it still appear to be embedded? FWIW, your code worked fine for me as well.

Comment: Yeah even in view source. If I view other peoples websites with inspect element I cannot open script like I do mine. They are actually linked in other websites where as mine should be. I even tried taking out all the PHP and it still didn't seem to make a difference. I am completely at a loss here.

Comment: On your live site, you may want to fix this line:
var pass = login["login"]["password"].value;